# Let $K$ and $K'$ be local field, and $v$ and $v'$ be it's valuation. Suppose $K'/K$ is unramified

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory, local-field

> Let $K$ and $K'$ be local field, and $v$ and $v'$ be it's valuation.
> Suppose $K'/K$ is unramified, then, for all $u'∈K'$,there exists $u∈K$
> such that $u/u'∈R'^×$.

My attempt: To probe this, $v'(u/u')＝v'(u)-v'(u')＝v(u)-v'(u')$, so, let $u'$ be $v'(u)$-th power of prime element of $K$, then, $v'(u/u')＝0$ and this $u$ is what we wanted.

Is my attempt correct?

This question is from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', p198.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks right, except that your final sentence, starting “so” looks as if in two places, you were careless about distinguishing among $u$, $u'$ and $\mathbf u$, but what malice led you to use the two letters $\mathbf u$ and $u$?

Comment: Thank you very much, I modified.